# SQL Delete Command

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to delete a joining tables with the same lbhc_lb_sku in table lif_bookhascategory and lb_sku in table lif_books. I can't delete it.

Here's my SQL command:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM lif_books FROM lif_books CROSS JOIN lif_bookshascategory WHERE (lif_books.lb_sku = @lb_sku) AND (lif_bookhascategory.lbhc_lb_sku = @lb_sku)">
```

That returns:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.
```

Comment: Can you give more detail on the action you want to perform? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to delete a joining tables with the same lbhc_lb_sku in table lif_bookhascategory and lb_sku in table lif_books..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this on my own database and it works.

```
DELETE lif_bookshascategory, lif_books
FROM lif_bookshascategory
INNER JOIN lif_books
WHERE lbhc_lb_sku = lb_sku
```

Comment: i had two tables lif_bookhascategoy.lbhc_lb_sku and table lif_book.lb_sku

Answer (score 2):

Officially, the SQL specification does not provide for using a Join in an action query (Insert, Update or Delete). In this case, it is simpler to use a more universal format:

```
Delete lif_books
Where lb_sku = @lb_sku
    And Exists  (
                Select 1
                From lif_bookhascategory
                Where lbhc_lb_sku = @lb_sku
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
DELETE lif_bookshascategory, lif_books
FROM lif_bookshascategory
INNER JOIN lif_books 
  ON lif_bookshascategory.lbhc_lb_sku = lif_books.lb_sku
```

[Here's the reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: @SilverFang: Are you using MySQL? I've tested a similar statement on my MySQL' delete test1,test2 from test1 inner join test2 on id1=id2;' and it works.